# PhpStorm doesn't get the folder's configuration when running a single test method

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

I have a Laravel project with three test directories - Browser, Feature, and Unit.

In Run/Debug configurations I've configured the Feature and the Unit directories to use `phpunit.xml` while the Browser directory uses `phpunit.e2e.xml`. I've also created a default configuration for all tests which uses the `phpunit.xml`.

If I open a class that is in the Feature/Unit directories and run a single test method or the whole class, it picks the default configuration, but when I run a single test method in the Browser directory, it uses `phpunit.xml` instead of `phpunit.e2e.xml`.

If I select a directory and run tests, it picks the proper configuration, but when I open a class in the Browser directory, it doesn't

Why doesn't PhpStorm use the configuration of the Browser directory recursively? How can I handle this problem?

Comment: I suggest adding screenshots (or even a small screencast) that would better illustrate your setup and the issue you are facing. For me it's difficult to understand all that purely from your description.

Comment: Per folder settings are not supported (when you have folders and want IDE to _automatically_ select specific config file) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-38634 . But specifying desired config file in actual Run/Debug Configuration should work just fine.

Comment: If you run a test method via PhpStorm, it won't override the folder configuration.

Comment: Details please. If you run a test from gutter area, it will use info from Default Run/Debug Configuration for PHPUnit (if no Defaults configured, it will use global one from Test Framework entry). If you have specific Run/Debug Configuration for that class/method/folder -- it will use config file that you specify in that entry.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know PhpStorm has never had this functionality and I wouldn't count on them adding it either. It seems way too specific.

What you can do though, is specify the configuration file you want to use through the commandline.

See: https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions

So your command would look something like this:

`phpunit tests\Unit\SomeTest.php --configuration phpunit.xml`

or

`phpunit tests\Browser\SomeTest.php --configuration phpunit.e2e.xml`

Comment: This is the only thing I can think of as well... :(

Comment: The other thing I can do is to change the default phpunit file before I start writting e2e tests.